# How do I disable a XAML entry in the debug configuration?

Tags: silverlight, debugging, bing-maps

How can I use something like the "#if" directive inside XAML.  I've declared a credentials key for my Bing Maps control and I want to turn off the key when I'm not live.  The key is in a resource dictionary.  How can I disable this in debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I wonder if this or something like it would work.

You could declare this public property in whatever the map's DataContext is (view model or otherwise).

```
public CredentialsProvider MyCredentialsProvider
{
#if DEBUG
    return null;
#else
    return new ApplicationIdCredentialsProvider(MyResources.MyCredentialsKey);
#endif
}
```

([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.clienttokencredentialsprovider.aspx) says we should use [ApplicationIdCredentialsProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee682016.aspx).)

Then you can simply bind to this property, since [CredentialsProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.map.credentialsprovider.aspx) is a [dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.core.mapbase.credentialsproviderproperty.aspx):

```
<m:Map CredentialsProvider="{Binding MyCredentialsProvider}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently posted a blog post, [Managing the Visibility of Xaml Elements in Cross Platform Applications](http://www.abtsoftware.co.uk/News/tabid/93/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/26/Managing_Visibility_of_Xaml_elements_in_Cross-Platform_WPF_Silverlight.aspx), which described how to show or hide Xaml based on whether the build was Silverlight or WPF.

This basically used an attached property which when applied as follows would hide (or show) an element:

```
local:FrameworkVisibilityManager.VisibleIn="Silverlight"

// OR 

local:FrameworkVisibilityManager.VisibleIn="Wpf"
```

Unfortunately there's no way to exclude Xaml based on the configuration but you can certainly change properties such as Visibility based on the configuration.

Using the above method you could create an Attached Property called DebugCredentialsProvider which applies the credentials to a Bing Maps control only if in Debug.

Comment: Thanks! :-) It's used in a cross platform component I'm working on (see my profile)